# how do I match an element with a list?

Tags: python

I am trying to match `id` with `id_list` using a one-liner,following doesnt seem to work,how do I fix it?

```
id  = 77bb1b03
id_list = ['List of devices attached ', '572ea01e\tdevice', '77bb1b03\tdevice', '']
if id in id_list:
     print "id present"
else:
     print "id not present"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't matching on equality but on a substring of the values in the list, assuming you just want to match the start:
Note: assuming `id` is actually a string because it isn't a valid literal.

```
id  = '77bb1b03'
id_list = ['List of devices attached ', '572ea01e\tdevice', '77bb1b03\tdevice', '']
if any(i.startswith(id) for i in id_list):
    print "id present"
else:
    print "id not present"
```

Comment: Or ``any(id in i for i in id_list)`` if the id can also appear in the middle of one of the strings.

Comment: Indeed, I made the assumption of just matching the start.

Comment: Sure, just adding this as an extra piece of information

Answer (score 0):

First, fix your code:

```
id  = "77bb1b03" # needs to be a string
id_list = ['List of devices attached ', '572ea01e\tdevice', '77bb1b03\tdevice', '']
```

Then loop over the list and compare each string individually:

```
for s in id_list:
    if id in s:
        print "id %s present"%id
        break
else:
    print "id %s not present"%id
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:
Single liner as you demanded and id is a string!

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
... id  = '77bb1b03'
... id_list = ['List of devices attached ', '572ea01e\tdevice', '77bb1b03\tdevice', '']
... [print(item, 'ID present') for item in id_list if item and item.find(id)!=-1]
77bb1b03    device ID present
```

Thanks @Achampion for the left -> right execution !

Comment: Cause check for  `''` and `None`

Comment: For `None` you would need `item and item.find()` or it will error. And it's unnecessary for `''` the `find()` will already have failed the `!= -1`.

Comment: Yes right you are,  I was mainly skeptical for `''` thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A nasty, obscure, slower alternative to those that will/are shown. The `id` var seems to prefix list items, but not sure if you would ever have need to find the `id` "somewhere" inside a list element.

```
id  = 77bb1b03
id_list = ['List of devices attached ', '572ea01e\tdevice', '77bb1b03\tdevice', '']
if len(filter(lambda id_list_item: id_list_item.find(id) >=0 , id_list)):
    print "id present"
else:
    print "id not present"
```